# jQuery - fade divs in and out after another

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="about"><a href="#about" class="goto_about">About us<span>who we are</span></a></li>
    <li id="quickfacts">
        <a href="#">Quick facts
            <span class="quickfacts">text 1</span>
            <span class="quickfacts">text 2</span>
            <span class="quickfacts">text 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="blog"><a href="#blog" class="goto_blog">Blog<span>our blog</span></a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="#contact" class="goto_contact">Contact<span>get in touch</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS to display the span elements on hover:

```
li a span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
li a:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

What I want now is, when hovering over 'Quick facts' to fade in 'text 1'; after a couple of seconds fade it out and fade in 'text 2' and so on (in the same position).

I've tried these suggestions from other posts:

First try

```
jQuery.fn.fadeDelay = function() {
    delay = 0;
    return this.each(function() {
    $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(350);
    delay += 50;
    });
});

$(".quickfacts").fadeDelay();
```

Second try

```
$(".quickfacts").hide().each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i*5000).fadeIn(5000);
});
```

Third try

```
$.fn.rollingText = function(number, time){
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
    this.fadeIn(time).fadeOut(time);
    if(i != number - 1) this.delay(time);
}
return this;
}
$(".quickfacts").rollingText(8, 2000);
```

The issue with the first two is all texts appear at once on hover, like the rest of the span elements, and disappear on mouseout.

The problem with the last one, which is the closest I've come to make it work, is all divs are fading in at once (but at least they fade in and out), how can I change this?  Also, how can I make the fadeIn cyclic, as opposed to stopping at 8 in this case? and can the fadeIn and fadeOut speeds be different?

Perhaps this is not the best solution, I'd also appreciate if someone can advise on my first two tries and where did I go wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, comments on your attempts.
First and second try you never fade out any elements.
Third try when you call fadeIn and fadeOut chained like that the latter won´t wait for first one to finish, use callback method instead, see my answer below for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I put together a code snippet that might work.

first add a class "hoverme" to the a that contains spans

```
   <a class="hoverme" href="#">Quick facts
        <span class="quickfacts">text 1</span>
        <span class="quickfacts">text 2</span>
        <span class="quickfacts">text 3</span>
    </a>
```

css

.quickfacts { display:none; }

javascript, fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JBzNm/1/

```
var isFadeable = false;
var position = 0;
var quickfacts = $(".quickfacts");
var qlength = quickfacts.length;

function fadeMe() {
    if (!isFadeable) {
        return;
    }
    var element = quickfacts.get(position); //get element to fade in
    $(element).fadeIn(function() {
        $(element).delay(2000).fadeOut(function() {            
            position++; //move position to get next element
            if (position == qlength) {
                position = 0; //start over
            }
            fadeMe();
        });
    });
}


//bind mouse events

$(".hoverme").mouseover(function(e) {
    isFadeable = true;
    fadeMe();

});
$(".hoverme").mouseout(function(e) {
    isFadeable = false;
    quickfacts.fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it out on JSFiddle:
**http://jsfiddle.net/missaghi/FZm3B/10/**

The CSS

```
li a span {
    display:none;
}
```

The script

```
function rotate(anchor) {
    if ($(anchor).attr("looper") === "true") {
        var nextone = $(anchor).find("span:visible").next();
        nextone.hide();
        if ($(anchor).find("span:visible").index() == ($(anchor).find("span").length - 1)) {
            nextone = $(anchor).find("span:first");
        }
        if ($(anchor).find("span").length > 1) //dont- loop singles
        {
            $(anchor).find("span:visible").fadeOut(400, function() {
                $(this).hide();
                nextone.hide().fadeIn(400);
            });
        }
        if ($(anchor).find("span:visible").length == 0) {
            $(anchor).find("span:first").hide().fadeIn(400);
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            rotate(anchor);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

$("li").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("looper", "true");
    rotate(this);
}, function() {
    $(this).attr("looper", "false");
    $(this).find("span").hide();
});
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much for all the detail.  I chose the other answer arbitrarily because both worked. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped. Rather than choosing arbitrarily, consider: 
1. this answer was submitted one hour sooner
2. this answer has more votes.

Comment: Actually I thought I saw Martin Larsson's answer a couple of minutes before, which is why I chose it, but I might be mistaken.  I still gave you an upvote because your answer was spot on too :)

Answer (score 1):

EDITED (refined the code)

Well, 5 hours too late to the party. Here are my 2c as an exercise:

```
<style type='text/css' media='screen'>
    li      { list-style: none; }
    li div  { clear:both; float:left; text-align:left; display:block; width:400px; }
    li a    { float:left; text-align:left; width:150px; }
    li span { float:left; text-align:left; display:none; }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    jQuery( function () {
        $('.nav').on( { 
            mouseenter : function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.addClass('mouseIN');
                if ($this.hasClass('mouseOUT')) $this.removeClass('mouseOUT');
                setTimeout( function () {
                    if ($this.hasClass('mouseIN')) {
                        var iCount = $this.find('span').length;
                        function showItem(i) {
                            if ($this.hasClass('mouseIN')) {
                                $this.find('span:eq('+i+')').slideDown(500).delay(1000).slideUp(1000);
                                if ((i<iCount) && (iCount > 1)) setTimeout( function () {
                                    i++;
                                    i = (i < iCount) ? i : 0;
                                    showItem(i);
                                },2501);
                            }
                        };
                        if (iCount > 1) 
                            showItem(0) 
                        else $this.find('span:eq(0)').slideDown(500);
                    }
                },200);
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.addClass('mouseOUT');
                if ($this.hasClass('mouseIN')) $this.removeClass('mouseIN');
                setTimeout( function () {
                    if ($this.hasClass('mouseOUT')) {
                        $this.find('span').slideUp(1000);
                    }
                },200);
            }
        }); //li .nav
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="about" class='nav' >
            <div>
                <a href="#about" class="goto_about">About us</a>
                <span>who we are</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="quickfacts" class='nav' >
            <div>
                <a href="#">Quick facts</a>
                <span>text 1</span>
                <span>text 2</span>
                <span>text 3</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="blog" class='nav' >
            <div>
                <a href="#blog" class="goto_blog">Blog</a>
                <span>our blog</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="contact" class='nav' >
            <div>
                <a href="#contact" class="goto_contact">Contact</a>
                <span>get in touch</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Sample: http://zequinha-bsb.int-domains.com/menuing.html

I don't know about reinventing the wheel. I avoid plug-ins at any cost or use them as a way of getting to learn how to solve the problem.

40,000+ years ago, "we" were able to build pyramids. Today, with all the technology available (plug-ins), we cannot even mimic one. How about another 40,000 years from now? 40tb program to display "Welcome"?

I understand that this is not a forum and SO enforce that and they are very right. There are three+ ways of doing the hovering:

hover

mouseover/mouseout

mouseenter/mouseleave

They all have their own little faults. Thanks to jQuery, they can be "plugged-in" easily in the same code with the only difference being awarded to hover.

Nice exercise!

Comment: @zequinha-bsbAgree, I try to stay away from plugins too.  Your example worked very nicely, thank you.